# What is the word/phrase for your two friends, who are in a relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

The closest I could find was this [ELL question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/73538/how-do-you-call-2-friends-who-are-together-without-mixing-it-up-with-a-couple-o).

My wife and I often hang out with our two friends, who are married (or another similar group who are not).  I'm looking for a succinct way to say:

> Oh, we're going to hang out with our [couple-friends], Bonnie and Clyde,
>   this weekend.

except replacing **couple-friends** with a phrase that doesn't sound stupid and implies that the two persons are in a relationship.

Comment: Sally, I'm pretty sure the "stupid sounding" term "couple friends" was invented because there's not a better term. Unless you like the more old-fashioned "we're double-dating with Bonnie and Clyde this weekend."

Comment: @1006a I've considered it....

Comment: There is no single word.  This is expressed 100 different ways, depending in part on how veiled the implications are intended to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps:

> *We're having a couples get-together with our friends Bonnie and Clyde this weekend.*

This avoids the use of *couple-friends* (or *coupled-friends*), but still very much implies the same thing. At any kind of couples event, those who attend will normally be couples.

---

I was asked in a comment about the use of the possessive apostrophe. Both forms can be used. It seems that the version without the apostrophe is currently more common, although the plural possessive used to be more common in the past.

This is suggested by [Google Books NGram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couple%27s%20retreat%2C%20couples%20retreat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouple%20%27s%20retreat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouples%20retreat%3B%2Cc0), where I've used a query based on the more common *couples retreat*, *couples' retreat* and *couple's retreat*:

[image: couples retreat]

(I also put the singular possessive into the query for further comparison.)

Comment: should it actually be couples'?

Comment: @goodguy5 Do you mean in my sentence? Yes. We say *a couples retreat*, even if only one couple is going, because it's a retreat meant for all couples who want to go (in general). But in the specific case of my sentence, there would be two couples anyway.

Comment: No, I mean "couple + 's' + apostrophe". Should it be a possessive plural couple? I'm not suggesting, I'm very unsure.

Comment: @goodguy5 I've updated my answer. In short, it's a matter of preference if you want to use the possessive apostrophe or not.

Comment: If I'm [looking at the data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=couple%27s+retreat%2Ccouples+retreat%2Ca+couple%27s+retreat%2Ca+couples+retreat%2Ca+couples%27+retreat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccouple%20%27s%20retreat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccouples%20retreat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20couple%20%27s%20retreat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20couples%20retreat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20couples%20%27%20retreat%3B%2Cc0) right, if there's an article before it, it takes an apostrophe after the S. If there's no article it doesn't take an apostrophe at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here are various options:

1. Oh, we're going to hang out with the Smiths this weekend. (If married and share last name)
2. Oh, we're going to hang out with Mr. & Mrs. Smith this weekend. (If married and share last name)
3. Oh, we're going to hang out with Bonnie and her husband this weekend. (If married, regardless of last name)
4. Oh, we're going to hang out with Bonnie and her boyfriend this weekend. (where "boyfriend" can be replaced with relationship status (i.e. finance, lover, mistress, etc)).

Comment: I think the OP is looking for some phrase that would describe the couple who are living _in unwedded bliss_, rather than legally bound. In that case, they would not share the same last name. As well, not all women take their husband's name when they get married.

Comment: @Cascabel Option 3 works if they are married and don't share the same last name. Option 1 & 2 are for if they are married and share a last name. Now, thanks to your comment, option 4 satisfies non-married couples living in sin.  ;)

Comment: OMG..I hope that last comment was a quip...:-)

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> We're going to hang out with our friend Bonnie, and her partner/boyfriend/husband/datemate/romantic match, our friend Clyde, this weekend.

Attributing one of them to the other using a title creates an unambiguous association that the other friends are also in a relationship. It also avoids implying that y'all aren't necessarily friends with Clyde as much as you are friends with Bonnie.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just say "Bonnie and Clyde"?

Simply saying their names together makes clear that they are connected.

It will sound stilted (*artificially or affectedly lofty; unnaturally elevated; formally pompous* (OED)) if you use a label for their relationship that they themselves do not use.

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't the word

> friends

Cover this?

> We are seeing  our friends bonnie and clyde this weekend.

Does the fact they are a couple really actually matter?